# Can I change a width or any other style of an element px by px as I scroll down with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with a width of 100px, I want to reduce the width by 1px on every scroll step so it looks as if the div is animated when I scroll down or up the page. So when I scroll down a 100 steps the div disappears. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution using a few lines of jQuery.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e){
     $('#box').css("width", 100-$(window).scrollTop());    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vwrr6Lv1/1/

EDIT:

If you need to start doing fancier animations, I recommend checking out jQuery Transit which supports CSS3 transforms and transitions, e.g

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e){
    $('#box').transition({'perspective':'100px', 'rotateY': 100-$(window).scrollTop()}, 0);    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vwrr6Lv1/3/

jQuery Transit is a great extension of jQuery.animate that supports CSS3 transitions and transforms. http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Answer (score 0):

you can use [skrollr.js](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) to achive animation on scroll. but other than this you also can add animate.css, parallax effects as they used in the site you mentioned

Comment: How am I going to achieve this with animate.css? adding classess on scroll? can you show me an example please?

Comment: Read a little about **waypoint.js** you will have an ideaa of how to add or remove classes as the element appear or disappear in viewport